# Histogram is not showing up in R? Specifically the viewer pan

Tags: r

Here is my code:

```
#part ii, creating a histogram for the completely randomized design and include the p-value mark.
TreatmentS<-c(1.067, 1.948, 0.980, 1.439, 2.537, 3.742, 2.316, 2.214, 5.448)
TreatmentT<-c(0.453, 1.143, 1.503, 1.861, 0.630, 0.378, 1.606, 1.590, 2.371)
experi<-c(TreatmentS,TreatmentT)
N<-choose(18,9)
res<-numeric(N)
library(combinat)
index<-combn(1:18,9)
for(i in 1:N)
{
  res[i] <- mean(experi[index[,i]])-mean(experi[-index[,i]])
  }
hist(res, xlab='ybarS-ybarT', main='Randomization Distribution of difference in means') 
observed<-mean(TreatmentS)-mean(TreatmentT) 
abline(v=observed, col="blue")
```

[image]

But when I do it in Rcloud, it executes it:
[image]

How can I solve this issue? Do I need to download a package?

Comment: Try running `dev.off()` (possibly multiple times until it gives you and error) and then re-running the last three lines of your code.

Comment: [Images should not be included with questions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please remove images. Images require more bandwidth than text: a simple 200 byte text snippet costs a thousand times less bandwidth than a 200 KB image. Since Stack Overflow serves hundreds of millions of views a day, this increase in bandwidth is significant

Answer (score 2):

Remove the code within at the top of the R Cell:  include = False